# What Defines What Category A Post Picks (if in multiple)

Tags: posts, categories, permalinks, menus, tags

If I have a post in multiple categories, what defines what category shows up in the URL? Assuming I have permalinks setup as `/%category%/%postname%` is it the ID or the name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress always use the category with lowest ID. You can use plugins such as the Hikari Category Permalink plugin to change that however.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hikari-category-permalink/